# Which is the environment variable for Mono/C# library DLLs?

Tags: linux, debian, environment-variables, mono, c#

I'm running the frozen Debian 7.0 Testing/Wheezy.

Here is my C# sample code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public class Simple : Form
{
    public Simple()
    {
       Text = "Simple";
       Size = new Size(250, 200);
       CenterToScreen();
    }

    static public void Main()
    {
       Application.Run(new Simple());
    }
}
```

I got the above C# WinForms code sample working in Monodevelop by using the System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms references as well as in the command line when compiling with the following command:

```
mcs /tmp/Simple.cs -r:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Windows.Forms.dll \
       -r:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll
```

I'm trying to make the `mcs` command work without needing to use the `-r` switch/parameter (which, by the way, I cannot find information on by looking through man mcs - I basically found this switch/parameter on some random website and it worked).

To check if it worked temporarily, I issued

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Windows.Forms.dll:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll
```

prior to issuing `mcs /tmp/Simple.cs`, which failed with the errors within the following output:

```
deniz@debian:~$ cd /tmp
deniz@debian:/tmp$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Windows.Forms.dll:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll
deniz@debian:/tmp$ mcs Simple.cs 
Simple.cs(1,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Windows' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Simple.cs(2,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Drawing' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
deniz@debian:/tmp$
```

The above output tells me that the mcs compiler/utility is not seeing the dll files but I don't know what else to try.

Any help in getting the WinForms and Drawing libraries to be automatically “looked at” would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You put directories in `$PATH`, not files. Try changing that.

Comment: Aren't this libs installed in GAC? Why do you specify full path to them??

Comment: Which version of mono and compiler is installed on your system? (`mono --version`, `mcs --version`)

Comment: "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/mono/4.0;export MONO_PATH=$MONO_PATH:.:/usr/lib/mono/4.0:/usr/lib/mono/gac;mcs /tmp/Simple.cs" has the same errors.

mcs --version
Mono C# compiler version 2.10.8.1

mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           __thread
 SIGSEGV:       altstack
 Notifications: epoll
 Architecture:  amd64
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          softdebug 
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make the mcs command work without needing to use the -r switch/parameter

This is not possible, mcs will not look for libraries unless you tell it to look for them (which is done with -r:...).